# Why are consecutive spaces in the result of an evaluated expression collapsed in Light Table?

Tags: lighttable

Light Table appears to collapse multiple consecutive spaces.

```
Expected behavior: (str "hello   " "there") => "hello   there"
Actual behavior:   (str "hello   " "there") => "hello there"
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: @Sam Estep: your example has a single space in input. Use multiple spaces in input and you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did have multiple spaces in the source for my comment, but the Markdown renderer on this site collapses whitespace, so I edited that part out. When I copy the text of the call to `str` from your question and paste it into `lein repl` or `boot repl`, I get the output you give as the "Expected behavior".

Comment: Ok, this must be a bug in Light Table then. Added screenshot to OP.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it in Light Table and got the same result. Looks like someone has [already posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/uaBG0oySCKo) on the Light Table Google Group. I edited your question to clarify that it's more about Light Table than Clojure.

Comment: Yes, I posted it just now :D

Comment: Oh! I assumed that was someone else because of the different username. Hopefully the behavior will be fixed. :)

Comment: This isn't specific to Clojure.

Comment: Please submit an issue for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/new).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is "just" a display issue related to light table's HTML-based platform. You can confirm this by evaluating these expressions:

```
(= "hello     there" (str "hello     " "there")) ; true
(= "hello there"     (str "hello     " "there")) ; false
```